# How to stream audio with portaudio

Tags: c++, audio, libraries, portaudio

im having a new trouble.
Im using Portaudio, I already configured it and started the stream, but I don't know, how to play a sound, I don't know if portaudio can open a file and stream it, How can I tell portaudio what to play?

Thanks

Comment: Portaudio only gives you access to your sound device. The sound device will receive or send PCM data. Where this data comes from is your problem.

Comment: I tried using QT Phonon, but portaudio its not doing anything, so I think that I need to send some type of data to the portaudio, I think... How can I do it? (libsndfile is not workin cause I need mp3 format)

Comment: It sounds like your problem is not with portaudio but with reading mp3 files. I think libsox will do this.

Comment: Do you know any library that can work with portaudio and can get the music file information?